# Yii - multiple urls mapped to single controller/action

Tags: php, yii, content-management-system, url-routing

One of the things Yii is good for is creating content management systems and similar on the fly. Such systems are generally light weight and scalable as they take advantage of the Yii framework and only use required features, something not accomplish-able by using of the shelf open-source CMS solutions such as Drupal.

I have used it in the past to do so, but with minimal sophistication. For instance, the user is able to edit the content, however I have hard coded controller/actions/view files and sent the content to each page.

How would I go about ramping my content management system creation up a notch and allow for the creation of pages programatically? I want to make it so the user can create a new page and designate a URL.

I have in mind to re-use the same controller and map this to different view files depending on user choices, but I'm open to other ways of solving this problem which I presume others must need to solve.

Also, allowing the user to designate a URL is an important feature, how can this be delivered?

Apologies for the long text based question. I could not think how to capture my use case appropriately in any other format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a real question, and not constructive... You should add more details about your existing models/views/controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Create table called, for example, `users_articles_uris`.

The table will contain primary key and the URI itself (e.g. `my-cool-title-for-something`).
In the future, it will become: `yoursite.com/my-cool-title-for-something`
or `yousite.com/controller/action/<users_special_uri>`.

By `.htaccess` or with the Yii routing, you will:

1. Get the URI;
2. Find it in the database;
3. Get article's id;
4. Find the article;
5. Print the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

The options commonly used, is store the URI in the database.
in the same row with users content, or create a table to store URI's and id reference to users content.

when the request made, just pull the requested uri data from DB (because the uri's are not dynamic. or even so..) and show the content
(i think WP does something like that but also enterprise systems),

of course, cache it well :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please can you expand on storing the URI. I'm not familiar with this and it sounds like I should be.